# application running on port 3000 is not accessible from other systems

Tags: node.js, windows, ip, port, bind

there is nodejs running on PC (window)

When i set the port 8080 i can access my app from other system using **IP+PORT**.
Below are the config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    prodport: 4004,
    devport: 8080,
    apiUrl: {
        devAPI: 'http://localhost:4004',
        prodAPI: 'http://localhost:4004'
    }
};
```

But When i set port 3000 i cant access it from other System.
Below are the config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    prodport: 4004,
    devport: 3000,
    apiUrl: {
        devAPI: 'http://localhost:4004',
        prodAPI: 'http://localhost:4004'
    }
};
```

Comment: 8080 is a standard port and is usually open.  Check to see if your firewall is blocking 3000.

Comment: @T Gray ... can you help me firewall set up in windows server 2012